# Using IN clause in a native sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, in-operator, sql-in

We are trying to dynamically generate an IN clause for a native sql query to return a JPA entity.  Hibernate is our JPA provider.  Our code looks something like this.

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="fooQuery",
    queryString="select f from Foo f where f.status in (?1)"
)

....

Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("fooQuery");
q.setParameter(1, "('NEW','OLD')");
return q.getResultList();
```

This doesn't work, the in clause does not recognize any of the values passed in via this manner.  Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JPA supports named list parameters, in  your case:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="fooQuery",
    queryString="select f from Foo f where f.status in (?1)"
)

Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("fooQuery");

List<String> listParameter = new ArrayList<>();
listParameter.add("NEW");
listParameter.add("OLD");

q.setParameter(1, listParameter); 
return q.getResultList();
```

Comment: This is not a Native Query, so I guess it's not an acceptable answer?

Comment: JPA will generate SQL query with IN clause parameterized from Java list - resulting SQL query will contain native (SQL) IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to not use a composite parameter for your query, but to split it out individually.  Don't specify `('NEW','OLD')`; specify separate parameters of `'NEW'` and `'OLD'`.  That may help.

This, of course, may cause problems if your parameter lengths are undefined.