# Seting list in hibernate native query does not work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sql-update

I am new to Hibernate and based upon the documentation for native query, I expected following code to execute.

```
public boolean markStatusById(List<Integer> list, String newStatus) throws Exception {
        boolean statusUpdated = false;
        try {
            entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE MyTableEntity SET status = :newStatus WHERE my_table_id in (?1)",
                    MyTableEntity .class)
                    .setParameter(newStatus, newStatus)
                    .setParameter(1, list);
            statusUpdated = true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | TransactionRequiredException e) {
            throw new Exception(CLASS_NAME,"markStatusById", e);
        }
        return statusUpdated;
    }
```

However, for some reason, this does not work.

What is the correct way to achieve what is intended in above query. [One of My Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831990/using-in-clause-in-a-native-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Once you define your query, you need to run it. 
For an update use:

```
int updateCount = entityManager.executeUpdate();
```

A small tip on the side is, before you set the `statusUpdated`, you would want to check whether `updateCount` is > 0.

And one more tip based on the JPA recommendations, when you want to run a DML query (UPDATE / DELETE) it is advised to run that operation is a separate transaction. In your case, if you are using spring for example would be to set the propagation level on that method to `REQUIRES_NEW`:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public boolean markStatusById(List<Integer> list, String newStatus)
```

this is due to the fact that those kind of queries ommit the persistence context which is not updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and valuable suggestions. However, I was executing my query earlier too, just missed to place it in my question. The real issue is setting the list. If I run the same query with hardcoded IDs, it runs fine. The only issue is setting the IN parameter dynamically.

Comment: did you try without the parentheses? also try with a named param instead of a positional

Comment: also you are mixing named and positional.. try to stick to one strategy

Comment: I tried without parenthesis , and also with named and positional parameters separately , but did not work.

Comment: also, why do you pass the MyTableEntity .class as the second param?

Comment: and .. this is not a native query but a JPQL query as you use createQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use 

entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE MyTableEntity SET status = :newStatus WHERE my_table_id in (?1)",
                    MyTableEntity .class)
                    .setParameter(newStatus, newStatus)
                    .setParameterList(1, list);
            statusUpdated = true;
```

Comment: Did this work for you ? I tried this but it didn't work. Also what is the "list" referring to in `.setParameter("list", list)` ?

Comment: Can you share the structure of MyTableEntity  class?

Comment: It has just got an Id column and two String columns (status and name) and no dependency on any other table.

Comment: entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE MyTableEntity SET status = :newStatus WHERE my_table_id in (:list)",
                    MyTableEntity .class)
                    .setParameter(newStatus, newStatus)
                    .setParameterList(list, list);
            statusUpdated = true;